# Why rotor copper loss in induction motor doesn't change with slip

Tags: power, induction-motor, rotor

Why air gap power is consumed in `R2/s` but rotor copper power loss only in `R2`?
Transformer Equivalent circuit of Induction motor: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g37XlYaLSb9sbIHuVYDUP1XuDgW_h8TS/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1):

The power in R2/s is the sum of rotor copper losses plus electrical power converted to mechanical power. To look at both the losses and the mechanical power, you can divide R2 into to two parts, R2 and R2(1-s)/s. The rotor current is proportional to E2xR2/s, so the rotor current and the losses in the rotor are directly proportional to slip. The mechanical power developed in the rotor is also proportional to slip.

Answer (score 0):

In order to seperate copper loss and mechanical power from airgap power we divide \$\frac{R_2}{s}\$ two part; 
$$\frac{R_2}{s} = R_2 + \frac{1-s}{s}R_2 $$

The reason why seperate like this copper loss is simply power dissipated on rotor copper which can formulated \$3I_2 R_2\$. Therefore rotor loss doesn't depend on slip.

If you want to ask why we modelled rotor side equivalent circuit with \$\frac{R_2}{s}\$ , induced voltage at rotor is slip dependent.

[image: rotor]

$$sV_2 = I_2 (jX_2s+R_2) \> \> \> (1)$$

Think when s=1 case. All induced voltage happen due to transformer action
$$V_2 = I_2 (jX_2+R_2)$$

Or think s=0. Relative motion of the rotor is zero there is no flux change. \$V_2 = 0\$

If equation make sense to you, now you can model rotor side by multipliying \$\frac{1}{s}\$ both side of the equation (1) and model the rotor copper loss.

Answer (score -1):

That's by definition. All slip-dependent losses in the rotor are subsumed as iron losses, because the resistance of the iron body increases with the frequency of the rotor current greatly, because of the skin effect.

In contrary, the copper/aluminium losses in the rotor aren't dependent on the frequency of the rotor current.